# AWS ECR allow pull for all?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-registry, amazon-ecr

I've uploaded a few docker containers to AWS ECR. 
I'm trying to Docker Pull without any authentication, which doesn't seem to work.

I've read that there's a way to authenticate with a token for only 12 hours, this is not a good option for my setup. I'm trying to have the Registry available for all (if a token is absolutely necessary, it should be a single token for all, without a time limit).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In your use case Authentication Token is necessary. And unfortunately the AWS authentication token max time limit can be set up for upto 12 Hrs not more than that.